# Implementation of Median Maintenance

Tags: python, algorithm, heap

I am trying to solve a problem from an online course I am taking and I believe I am stuck.

This is the problem

> The goal of this problem is to implement the "Median Maintenance"
>   algorithm. The text file contains a list of the integers from 1 to
>   10000 in unsorted order; you should treat this as a stream of numbers,
>   arriving one by one. Letting xi denote the ith number of the file, the
>   kth median mk is defined as the median of the numbers x1,…,xk. (So, if
>   k is odd, then mk is ((k+1)/2)th smallest number among x1,…,xk; if k
>   is even, then mk is the (k/2)th smallest number among x1,…,xk.)
>
> Find the sum of the 1000 medians.

Below is the code I have and its outputs the wrong answer and I can't seem to figure out what's going wrong

```
import heapq
# all_ints = list(map(int, open("stanford_algo/course_2_graph_search/median.txt").read().splitlines()))
all_ints = [6331, 2793, 1640, 9290, 225, 625, 6195, 2303, 5685, 1354]
min_heap_elements =  [all_ints[0]] # has all elements more than median
max_heap_elements =  [all_ints[1]] # has all elements less than median
heapq.heapify(min_heap_elements) # has all elements more than median
heapq._heapify_max(max_heap_elements) # has all elements less than median
medians = []
medians.append(all_ints[0])
medians.append(all_ints[1]) #doing this because I can see the first two elements are in decreasing order

for i, next_int in enumerate(all_ints[2:],start=3):
    if next_int > min(min_heap_elements):
        heapq.heappush(min_heap_elements, next_int)
        heapq.heapify(min_heap_elements)
    elif next_int <=  max(max_heap_elements):
        max_heap_elements.append(next_int)
        heapq._heapify_max(max_heap_elements)
    else:
        if len(min_heap_elements) > len(max_heap_elements):
            max_heap_elements.append(next_int)
            heapq._heapify_max(max_heap_elements)
        else:
            heapq.heappush(min_heap_elements, next_int)
            heapq.heapify(min_heap_elements)
    if len(max_heap_elements) - len(min_heap_elements) > 1:
        extract = max_heap_elements.pop(0)
        heapq.heappush(min_heap_elements, extract)
        heapq._heapify_max(max_heap_elements)
        heapq.heapify(min_heap_elements)
    elif len(min_heap_elements) - len(max_heap_elements) > 1:
        extract = min_heap_elements.pop(0)
        max_heap_elements.append(extract)
        heapq._heapify_max(max_heap_elements)
        heapq.heapify(min_heap_elements)
    median = [max(max_heap_elements), min(min_heap_elements)][(i)%2]
    medians.append(median)

sum(medians)%10000 # should be 9335
```

I am using two heaps here. One to store the elements larger than the media in a minimum heap(`min_heap_elements`) and the other heap(`max_heap_elements`) to store elements smaller than the median. For each new element, if its smaller(or equal) than the largest element of the max heap, I add it to the `max_heap_elements`. i

If the new element is larger than the minimum element of the min heap I add it to `min_heap_elements`. If its neither of the cases, I see which heap is shorter and add it to that one.

However, there is something I am doing here and I can't put my finger on it.

**EDIT:**

These are the medians I get

```
>>> medians
[6331, 2793, 6331, 2793, 6331, 1640, 2793, 2303, 2793, 2303]
```

This what I am expecting

```
>>> correct_medians
[6331, 2793, 2793, 2793, 2793, 1640, 2793, 2303, 2793, 2303]
```

Comment: When you run this with a debugger, what is the first point when it behaves differently than you expected?

Comment: @ScottHunter, I have added some info in the edit section. It starts breaking away at the third median

Comment: @ScottHunter, I have made some updates to the code. While balancing the trees instead of doing  `pop(-1)`, I have changed that to `pop(0)`. I accidentally left that in. I have updated the `medians` in the edit section as well

Comment: This code may provide a useful [reference](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-median-from-data-stream/discuss/74047/JavaPython-two-heap-solution-O(log-n)-add-O(1)-find)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how you are computing the median from the two heaps, as the left one is not guaranteed to have one more element than the right one, when the index is odd.

Instead you should do

```
if len(max_heap_elements) == len(min_heap_elements):
    median = max(max_heap_elements)
elif len(max_heap_elements) > len(min_heap_elements):
    median = max(max_heap_elements)
else:
    median = min(min_heap_elements)
```

Also, note that if you are using heaps, is because you want to achieve a `O(nlogn)` solution, however, by repeatedly calling functions like `heapify`, `max` and `min`, you won't get the desired time complexity.

Instead of `min(min_heap_elements)` write `min_heap_elements[0]`, remove the `heapify` call after `heappush`, instead of list's `pop` use `heappop`.

Finally for the max heap you could have a list with the negated values, as the `heapq` module does not support max heaps, they only "support" some operations like `_heappop_max`, but there's no `_heappush_max`, so you will always need to call `_heapify_max`.

**EDIT:**
if time complexity is not a requirement, you could just the function `statistics.median_low` from the standard library.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Sebastian. I realize my error now. And thanks for the additional pointers. It's kinda my first time working with heaps, so I added a whole bunch of ops to ensure the structure is maintained. I took them off now and it works the same. Thanks for pointing that out. Also, you've used `max` and `min` operations in calculating medians, the same mistake I did that you pointed out :)

Answer (score 0):

I am going through the same course, so my solution is here.

```
import heapq
import statistics

with open('home_work_week3_Median.txt', 'r') as file:
    line = file.read().strip().split('\n')
file.close()
assert len(line) == 10000

# solution with heapq
nn = []
num = 0

for n, v in enumerate(line):

    nn.append(v) 

#     index = (len(nn) - 1) // 2 # here we get the index of new list
#     new = heapq.nsmallest(n+1, nn) # get the smallest num of heapqed list
#     print(new[index], new, index)

    # here we combine it into one line
    num += int(heapq.nsmallest(n+1, nn)[(len(nn) - 1) // 2])

num%10000


# solution with statistics lib
num = 0

for index, number in enumerate(test):
    num += int(statistics.median_low(test[:index+1]))

num%10000
```

I don't know if my solution is right, execution time is the same for both solution (about 11 sec). I am sure it could be better